# Acumatica - Extended graph children not showing when view

Tags: graph, acumatica

Good Day Sir / Ma'am,

I have a question regarding extending graphs in Acumatica.

I have extended the *SalesOrderEntry Graph* with 2 custom views namely *ReservationDetails and PropertyItems*. Everything is running well except when I try to fetch a record, the details on my PropertyItems view are not populating.

**EXTENDED GRAPH**

```
public class SOOrderEntryExt : PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
{

#region Selects

public PXSelect<RECOReservationDetail,
                    Where<RECOReservationDetail.reservationNbr,
                        Equal<Current<SOOrder.orderNbr>>>> ReservationDetails;


public PXSelectJoin<InventoryItem,
                    LeftJoin<RECOReservationDetail, On<InventoryItem.inventoryID,
                        Equal<RECOReservationDetail.inventoryID>,
                        And<RECOReservationDetail.reservationNbr,
                            Equal<Current<SOOrder.orderNbr>>>>>,
                    Where<InventoryItem.inventoryID, 
                        Equal<Current<RECOReservationDetail.inventoryID>>>> PropertyItems;
```

**CUSTOM TABLE - ReservationDetail DAC**

```
namespace RealEstate.DAC.CO
{
    [Serializable]
    public class RECOReservationDetail : IBqlTable
    {

        #region Reservation Nbr.

        [PXDBString(15, IsKey = true)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Reservation Nbr.")]
        [PXParent(typeof(Select<SOOrder, 
                            Where<SOOrder.orderNbr, 
                                Equal<Current<RECOReservationDetail.reservationNbr>>>>))]
        [PXDBDefault(typeof(SOOrder.orderNbr))]
        public virtual string ReservationNbr { get; set; }
        public abstract class reservationNbr : IBqlField { }

        #endregion

        #region Branch ID

        [PXDBInt]
        [PXSelector(typeof(Search<Branch.branchID>),
                    SubstituteKey = typeof(Branch.branchCD))]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Branch ID", Required = true)]
        [PXDefault(typeof(AccessInfo.branchID), PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
        public virtual int? BranchID { get; set; }
        public abstract class branchID : IBqlField { }

        #endregion

        #region Inventory ID

        [StockItem]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Inventory ID")]
        public virtual int? InventoryID { get; set; }
        public abstract class inventoryID : IBqlField { }

        #endregion
```

[Page - Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76Pgt.png)

The above image is the view when I'm trying to fetch an order from sales order. As you can tell, It populates the document details part except for the *Features Group*. I already put **CommitChanges = True** on the **Inventory ID** field so that it will fill in the necessary information for the features part, but sadly it doesn't fill in any data.

```
<px:PXSegmentMask ID="edInventoryID" runat="server" CommitChanges="True" DataField="InventoryID"></px:PXSegmentMask>
```

I tried debugging it, but the PropertyItems view always **returns null value**.

Thank you so much for the replies.

**UPDATE - 10/05/2018**

[Full Page Link](https://gist.github.com/linnaire/d749344d9d01e1dbf765475e9c0922ca)

[Full Extended Graph Link](https://gist.github.com/linnaire/65acaa3789796aa2b032ba68d768ff2a)

[Full DAC Link](https://gist.github.com/linnaire/e14e25406250e165696055193816c90b)

Comment: That's a pretty atypical design, it would help to have more complete code (full DAC and the ASPX source code).

Comment: Hello @HB_ACUMATICA,  I updated my question and added the full page, extended graph, and dac links. Thank you very much for the reply and the help. :)

Comment: In the Database do you have a CompanyID field in the RECOReservationDetail table?

Comment: It also appears you re-implemented the SalesOrder screen instead of extending it. Not something usual.

Comment: Unfortunately as it is, it is too difficult to replicate your example with the partial files you provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your main problem occurs because you re-implemented the Sales Order screen instead of extending it. While doing so you removed some important elements like the Document Details 'grid'.

If I just add your 2 Data Views to the original Sales Order screen without removing anything they appear to sync better. Notice it does pickup the Item description and item image properly (other blank fields is because I miss your custom DAC/Table):
[image]

To test this I extended original Sales Order instead of creating a new screen that is a copy of the orginal Sales Order. You likely removed too much of the original screen.

Comment: Thank you so much! Really help me a lot from understanding the behavior in acumatica. :D